# Get dnsName and hostedZoneId from HttpApi in the same stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

Using aws cdk, I am creating an `apigatewayv2.HttpApi` backed by lambda functions.

I would like to setup a custom domain (`apiCustomDomain`) name for this created API, however I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the `dnsName` and `hostedZoneId` from the created API to create an `ARecord`.

```js
    import * as apigateway2 from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2';

    const apiCustomDomain = new apigateway2.DomainName(this, 'api-custom-domain', {
        domainName: subDomainName,
        certificate: certificate
    });

    const api = new apigateway2.HttpApi(this, 'my-api', {
        apiName: 'my-api',
        defaultDomainMapping: {
            domainName: apiCustomDomain
        },
        createDefaultStage: true,
        disableExecuteApiEndpoint: false,
        defaultAuthorizer: new HttpIamAuthorizer()
    });

    new route53.ARecord(this, 'a-api-record', {
        zone: hostedZone,
        recordName: subDomainName,
        target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias({
            bind(record: IRecordSet, zone?: IHostedZone): AliasRecordTargetConfig {
                return {
                     dnsName: api.?????, // what to put here 
                     hostedZoneId: api.????? // what to put here
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Now in the v1 of `apigateway`, it was straightforward, we would get those values from the `domainName` property of the api, something like:

```js
   dnsName = api.domainName!.domainNameAliasDomainName
   hostedZoneId = api.domainName!.domainNameAliasHostedZoneId
```

But I can't find the same for the `apigatewayv2` library.

Comment: come back to us @Mehdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the existing Hosted Zone retrieved using `fromLookup` and a `ApiGatewayv2DomainProperties` target from the [Route53 targets module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53_targets.ApiGatewayv2DomainProperties.html) to the `ARecord`.

```js
const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'HostedZone', {
  domainName: domain,
});

new route53.ARecord(this, 'AliasRecord', {
  recordName: subdomain,
  zone,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(
    new targets.ApiGatewayv2DomainProperties(
      apiCustomDomain.regionalDomainName,
      apiCustomDomain.regionalHostedZoneId
    )
  ),
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I'm a bit confused as to how it could actually map the custom domain to the api's. 1- Is it due to the `defaultDomainMapping` in the `HttpApi`? 2- Also why is the domain name of the API different than its Invoke url?

Comment: Glad to help.  Yes, I believe you are correct, from what I see in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha-readme.html#custom-domain).

Comment: Understood, thank you.